# how to call external function in mongoose $where and passing this variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i need to write a query using mongoose in nodejs. there is a schema for users where user's current location is stored using longitude and latitude. now i have a user's current location and i need to find all users whose distance is not more than 10 miles from the user. to calculate geolocation distance i can use node modules. the fact is, i was trying to use $where of mongoose to search, but i can not use there any outside's functions. the query is much alike below:

```
User.find().$where( calculate(this.current_location) +">10").exec(function(){
//body
});
```

here is like the calculate function:

```
calculate(location){ 
return distance(location,req.user.location)
}
```

the fact is i can not pass this instance. it is not referring the users on database. how can i do that? :( thanx in advance

Comment: Why aren't you using Mongo's [built-in support](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/) for geolocation?

Comment: bcoz i m not getting in what way they calculate the distance. the result is not understandable to me :(

Comment: alright ! i get it how to it with mongodb...but having lots of trouble when used mongoose :( finally did it .. thank u very much

Comment: Cool!  Nice work powering through it and doing it right.

Comment: But "how to call external function in mongoose $where and passing this variable" ????