# complex mongoose query with $where

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Im having a real headache with a mongoose query, I am still quite new to it and wondered if anyone could suggest a solution.

I have the following fields in a gallery collection.

- status (value of 'public' or 'restricted'),
- restriction (value of 'canview' or 'cantview'),
- canview (an array of user ids (ObjectIds) of users permitted to view gallery)

I then check fields against the current userID, to see what items are viewable.

how would it be possible to select ALL of the following items

a) all items with 'status' = 'public'

b) all items with 'status' = 'restricted' WHERE 'restricted' = 'canview' AND 'canview' contains the  UserID

I wasnt able to do this using $and and $or, so tried with $where instead. Using the following global function

```
var existsInArray = function(str,arr) {
    // nb: remember we have typeof ObjectID, so lets convert to strings first!
    var newarr = arr.toString().split(',');
    // now compare..
    if(newarr.inArray(str)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

I was hoping to do something like this...

```
exports.listviewable = function(req, res) {

    var reqID = req.user.id;

    Gallery
        .find()
        .$where(function () {
          return this.status === "public" || ( this.status === "restricted" && this.restriction === "canview" && existsInArray(reqID, this.canview));
        })
        .sort('-created')
        .exec(function(err, galleries) {
            if(err) {
                return res.status(400).send({message:getErrorMessage(err)})
            } else {
                res.json(galleries);
            }
        }); 

};
```

but this wasnt working  - it appears I wasnt able to use the global existsInArray function in the $where clause ?

Is it possible to do it like this ( similar unresolved question here [how to call external function in mongoose $where and passing this variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605620/how-to-call-external-function-in-mongoose-where-and-passing-this-variable)), or is there a better way to do it with AND and OR ?

Comment: You should not be even trying. The base logic does not **need** JavaScript that I can see. So what is `existsInArray()` supposed to be doing? You need to avoid JavaScript evaluation at all costs as is is "SLOW" ( clear enough?) and is just about always avoided by using proper native operators and/or restructuring data. So show what your magic function is supposed to do. I am sure we can do it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `$where` function can't refer to your local `existsInArray` function because the `$where` function is executed on the server where that local function doesn't exist.

But you shouldn't be using `$where` anyway, as you can do with with a simple `$or` query that takes advantage of the fact that you can directly query array fields like `canview` with "contains" behavior:

```
Gallery
    .find({
        $or: [
            {status: 'public'},
            {status: 'restricted', restriction: 'cantview', canview: reqId}
        ]
    })
    .sort('-created')
    .exec(function(err, galleries) {...});
```

Comment: You missed the `existsInArray()` magic call. I'd like to know what the OP thinks it does for them.

Comment: My read was that the OP was using that function to implement the `'canview' contains the UserID` logic of the query they're looking for.

Comment: Fair enough guess. It is probably what they meant. Hopfully it's a simple array of "ids". If not I guess there will be questions.

Comment: thanks guys, cannot believe it was that simple.. I think what was throwing me a bit was the 'canview' contains the UserId part of it. the existsInArray() call I used in a previous update function - it was necessary as the controller received an array of strings which then needed to be converted back to User ObjectIds as defined by the model Schema - I guess I just assumed it would be easiest to re-use that function here, but looking at this it seems I wouldnt need to make that conversion with mongoose. brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'd recommend hitting the mongo docs - they have alot of info on this.

a)

```
Gallery.find({status: 'public'}, function(err, data){
    console.log(data)
});
```

b)

```
Gallery.find({status: 'restricted', restricted: 'canview', canview: reqID }, function(err, data){

});
```

or both together with sorting...

```
Gallery.find({$or:[
   {status: 'public'}, 
   {status: 'restricted', restricted: 'canview', canview: reqID }
]}, {
   sort:{created:-1}
}, function(err, data){
   console.log(data)
});
```